# TCL Amazon S3 Interaction

Tags: amazon-s3, tcl

I have a TCL/TK Windows application that creates a small executable that I distribute to my customers.  Because it is an exe file I can not email the file.  Instead I upload it to an Amazon S3 bucket then create a URL link and email the link to them.  They download the file from the link and run the exe.

What I would like to do is add the ability upload to an Amazon bucket within the application that will enable me to upload the file and create a URL that I can copy and email to the customer.  I have seen Amazon S3 API's written for other languages, python, java, but not TCL.  Has anyone done this? How hard is it? Can you point me to a tutorial?

Actually I do not have to use a S3 bucket.  If there is another suggestion for how to distribute small files to customers from within TCL programs I am open to suggestions.  Besides what has been laid out above the only other requirement is that multiple people must be able to upload to the same location, the TCL program runs on Windows and I would like to not use a 3rd party program.  Security is not a major concern, nor is privacy, these things are handled other ways.

Comment: Recommendations are out of scope for Stack Overflow… but Dropbox is really easy I find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Tcl does provide an [S3](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/S3.html) package, but since I don't have Amazon S3 account, I cannot test it out.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  It looks like for what I need this should be simple to implement.  Thanks for the info.